# Python, applying a formula on each element in an numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Alright, so this is what im trying to do.

Lets say my input into the function is (D,y)
Y is how many elements in the array, so if Y is 3 the array is ([1,2,3]) if it's 51, the array is ([1,2,3....51]).
so what im doing for this is

```
def okay(D,y):
   T=np.arange(y)
```

the equation i want to apply to the array is the following

k= D*(T[k+1]-T[k])+D*(T[k-1]-T[k])

So, k is any index in the T array, D is the value specified at the start of the function.

So, what is basically happening, is that the new value of any element of the array after the operation is D*([the element in front of it]-[the element itself])+ D*([the elemeny before it]-[the element itself])

So, this generally seems simple enough. I was able to do it on a simple array  by specifying each individual index

```
d=3
T=np.array([23,17,46,2])
T[1] = d*(T[2]-T[1])+d*(T[0]-T[1])
print(T)
```

However, my problems appear whenever i try and make a function that does this for every single element in the area. I cant figure out how to set the k aspect, such that the function understands that i mean any point in the array. So, if i have an array of 5000 values, it will do the operation on each one, using the index itself, and the one infront/behind it.

I tried using int and i and "for element in T" but it gives me never ending errors.

Secondly, the function should do a different equation for endpoints, since they dont have any value prior or after them:

change in T[0] = D*(T[1]-T[0])

change in T[L-1] = D*(T[L-2]-T[L-1])

I don't know how to incorporate these into the function.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: T[1] = d*(T[2]-T[1])+d*(T[0]-T[1]) 
This will change T[1] value and the changed value will be used when T[2] is computed. Is that what you want?

Comment: just do a loop and build up your resulting array element by element. Within this loop, add the two special cases (end points)

Comment: Try to calculate most values with slices, `T[1:]`,`T[:-1]`,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you intentionally changing `T` as you go though it?  So that one value depends on modified `T` from the previous step?  Or is each step independent?

Lets assume the latter, since it is simpler.  In that case we, I think, calculate:

```
In [528]: T = np.arange(10)
In [529]: R = np.zeros(10)
In [533]: for i in range(10):
    if i==0:
        R[i]=3*(T[i+1]-T[i])
    elif i==9:
        R[i]=2*(T[i-1]-T[i])
    else:
        R[i]=3*(T[i+1]-T[i])+2*(T[i-1]-T[i])
   .....:         
In [534]: R
Out[534]: array([ 3.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -2.])
```

the middle values aren't very interesting since `T` is uniformly spaced; we'll live it that for now.

The middle values can be calculated all at one, using slices:

```
In [535]: 3*(T[2:]-T[1:-1])+2*(T[:-2]-T[1:-1])
Out[535]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
In [536]: R[1:-1]=3*(T[2:]-T[1:-1])+2*(T[:-2]-T[1:-1])
In [537]: R
Out[537]: array([ 3.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -2.])
```

Or we can get the end values as well with:

```
In [542]: R = np.zeros(10)
In [543]: R[:-1] += 3*(T[1:]-T[:-1])
In [544]: R[1:]  += 2*(T[:-1]-T[1:])
In [545]: R
Out[545]: array([ 3.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -2.])
```

Now if `R[i-1]` enters into the calculation of `R[i]`, we'll have to reconsider the vectorized calculations:

```
In [546]: R = T.copy()
In [547]: for i in range(10):
    if i==0:
        R[i]=3*(T[i+1]-T[i])
    elif i==9:
        R[i]=2*(R[i-1]-T[i])
    else:
        R[i]=3*(T[i+1]-T[i])+2*(R[i-1]-T[i])
   .....:         
In [548]: R
Out[548]: array([   3,    7,   13,   23,   41,   75,  141,  271,  529, 1040])
```

There are some cumulative functions and unbuffered calculations that might be useful

```
np.cumsum()
np.add.at()
```